# V8/Node.js increase max allowed String length

Tags: node.js, v8

AFAIK V8 has a known [hard limit on the length of allowed `String`s](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/14170). Trying to parse >500MB Strings will pop the error:

```
Invalid String Length
```

Using V8 flags to increase the heap size doesn't make any difference

```
$ node --max_old_space_size=5000 process-large-string.js
```

I know that I should be using Streams instead. However is there any way to increase the maximum allowed `String` length anyway?

---

**Update:** Answer from @PaulIrish below indicates they upped it to 1GB - but it's still not user-configurable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, no, there is no way to increase the maximum allowed `String` length.

It is hard-coded in the source, and a lot of code implicitly relies on it, so while allowing larger strings is known to be on people's wishlist, it is going to be a lot of work and won't happen in the near future.

Comment: Do you happen to know the reason for this limitation? Why does `String` have that particular max length in V8?

Comment: It dates back all the way to 2010. Back then, 512MB was the overall heap limit, and I guess it was a no-brainer to decide that no single string could/should be bigger than the heap ;-) (512 MB = memory consumption of a UTF-16 string with length 2^28.)

Comment: It's safe to assume you're on the V8 team.  Thanks for everything :)

Comment: This is no longer the case. See my answer.

Comment: @PaulIrish well , it actually still IS the case that there is a maximum limit; the limit was increased to roughly 1gig

Answer (score 14):

In summer 2017, V8 increased the maximum size of strings **from ~256MB to ~1GB**. Specifically, from `2^28 - 16` to `2^30 - 25` on 64-bit platforms. [V8 ticket.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=6148#c10)

This change landed in:

- V8: 6.2.100
- Chromium: 62.0.3167.0
- Node.js: 9.0.0

Comment: This appears to have regressed back tp 2^28 due to pointer compression and recently bumped back up to 2^29 (0.5GB) as per https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/ea56bf5513d0cbd2a35a9035c5c2996272b8b728 :(