# Node Memory Usage & Out Of Memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

A bit of confusion here. I have a node service crashing. However, heap used is much lower than heap total?

```
{"rss":8120283136,"heapTotal":7640494080,"heapUsed":4244076904,"external":33576},"msg":"STATS","v":1}

<--- Last few GCs --->

[1:0x2a1edc0] 30954759 ms: Mark-sweep 4017.1 (7221.0) -> 4017.1 (7152.0) MB, 2222.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.889, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested
```

Running with `--max-old-space-size=7168`

It looks to me that there should be at least 3 GB heap available?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: there is a strict standard limit for the memory usage in V8 of around 1.7 GB

Comment: @mehta-rohan that was a long ago... it has changed

Answer (score 2):

In `V8` there is a lot of hard coded size limits on built-in objects, you could reach one of them. Here's couple examples:

> FWIW, there are limits to everything: besides the maximum heap size,
>   there's a maximum String length, a maximum Array length, a maximum
>   ArrayBuffer length, a maximum BigInt size, a maximum stack size, etc.
>   Any one of those limits is potentially debatable, and sometimes it
>   makes sense to raise them, but the limits as such will remain. Off the
>   top of my head I don't know what it would take to bump this particular
>   limit by, say, a factor of two -- and I also don't know whether a
>   factor of two would be enough to satisfy your expectations.

V8 developer [jmrk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6036428/jmrk)

> In summer 2017, V8 increased the maximum size of strings from ~256MB
>   to ~1GB. Specifically, from  2^28 - 16 to 2^30 - 25 on 64-bit
>   platforms.

[V8/Node.js increase max allowed String length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533966/v8-node-js-increase-max-allowed-string-length)

> The limit is determined by:
>
> The FixedArray backing store of the Map has a maximum size of 1GB
>   (independent of the overall heap size limit) On a 64-bit system that
>   means 1GB / 8B = 2^30 / 2^3 = 2^27 ~= 134M maximum elements per
>   FixedArray A Map needs 3 elements per entry (key, value, next bucket
>   link), and has a maximum load factor of 50% (to avoid the slowdown
>   caused by many bucket collisions), and its capacity must be a power of
>   2. 2^27 / (3 * 2) rounded down to the next power of 2 is 2^24, which is the limit you observe.

[Maximum number of entries in Node.js Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452896/maximum-number-of-entries-in-node-js-map)

> However, the maximum length of an array according to the ECMA-262 5th
>   Edition specification is bound by an unsigned 32-bit integer due to
>   the ToUint32 abstract operation, so the longest possible array could
>   have 232-1 = 4,294,967,295 = 4.29 billion elements.

[Maximum size of an Array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript)

> Maximum length of a typed array in V8 is currently set to kSmiMaxValue
>   which depending on the platform is either:
>
> 1Gb - 1byte on 32-bit 2Gb - 1byte on 64-bit Relevant constant in the
>   code is v8::internal::JSTypedArray::kMaxLength (source).
>
> V8 team is working on increasing this even further on 64-bit
>   platforms, where currently ArrayBuffer objects can be up to
>   Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER large (2**53 - 1).

[What's the maximum size of a Node.js Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974375/whats-the-maximum-size-of-a-node-js-buffer)